# Blessings and other appeals to deities

Tags: discussion, comments, noise-reduction

Is SO an appropriate place for comments like

- God Bless SIMPLEXML
- God Bless you all...
- God bless you.....
- Thanks a lot and God bless.
- God blessed. I finally got the solution.
- Thank you and God Bless!
- God bless groovy! :)
- God bless me! I found a good method:
- God bless scripting languages and their "language features"...
- ..tc,god bless u...
- I'd like to wish you happy painting, and God bless my friend.
- May god bless [person's name here]
- please help, much appreciated. god bless :)

Etc.

Comment: Offensive? Really? You find "God bless you" offensive?

Comment: @Łukas not a dupe, the one here talk about *comments*, the other one about answers. Those are two very different things.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Not a dupe, for a different reason - there's no mention of deities in that question, as it seems to be dedicated to "thank you"s.

Comment: I'm sure there must be a questions about 'thank you' in questions, only I couldn't quickly find it. However, the answers from those about comments apply perfectly here. 'Thank you & CO' are noise, in both questions and answer. 'God bless you' is just another 'thank you' form.

Comment: I believe religion has no place on a technical site like SO.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I find "may you have a magically enchanted day" slightly offensive. I can deal with it though.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, and it has nothing to do with the “God” part. All “thanks” comments with no other substance are always subject to removal. (*All* comments are always subject to removal.) If you think they’re too chatty or not constructive, flag them as such.

So, for instance, your example here (assuming there was something beyond the colon) would be perfectly fine:

> - God bless me! I found a good method:

Comment: I believe this is in reference to a post made a few years ago he just edited http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159688/add-close-option-to-jquery-color-picker/3177882#3177882 - "The creator of the colorpicker helped and fixed the things I needed.  God bless the creator  =)" - I'm of the opinion this was fine as it was.

Comment: Ah, yep. I’d definitely consider that “too minor”.

Answer (score 12):

Only if those gods correctly answer the question.  But even in that case, an upvote is better, because even the gods have to worry about their reputation.

Comment: *cough* Jon Skeet *cough*